# Using Bayesian Networks to solve this localization problem?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, bayesian, bayesian-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm reading [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=F401AD9BD8D8C00D009D437F43DA3BEA?doi=10.1.1.330.5766&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper, which I'll summarize here:

---

> Let a sensor network (in this case, a network of radio receivers)
> consist of $N$ sensor nodes at locations $S = \{ S_1 \cdots S_N\}$.
> Let $S_i^x$ refer to the $x$-coordinate of the location of sensor node
> $i$, and $S_i^y$ refer to the $y$-coordinate. We assume locations in
> $2$-D space, but the same technique will work in $3$-D space as well.
>
> These locations are *not* known to us.
>
> Second, let there be $M$ radio-generating events at locations $E = \{
>  E_1 \cdots E_M\}$. Moreover, let $E_i^x$ and $E_i^y$ refer to the
> respective coordinates.
>
> These locations are *not* known to us.
>
> Finally, let the times of the radio-generating events (the "time of
> emission") be $T = \{ T_1 \cdots T_M \}$.
>
> These times are *not* known to us.
>
> **Goal**: to determine the coordinates ($E_i^x$, $E_i^y$) of each radio-generating event.
>
> Let there exist up to $M\cdot N$ variables $R_n^m$ that specify the
> time recorded at sensor node $S_m$ for sound $E_n$. We assume that
> $R_n^m$ is distributed as follows:
>
> $R_n^m \approx N(T_n + \frac{d(S_m,E_n)}{c},\sigma)$
>
> $d(S_m, E_n) = \sqrt{(S_m^x - E_n^x)^2 + (S_m^y - E_n^y)^2}$
>
> Where $c$ is the speed of light, $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of
> the error in recording times, and $N(\mu,\sigma)$ is a Normal
> distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.
>
> We encapsulate the relations between variables as  Bayesian network,
> and show how the localization problem reduces to that of maximum
> likelihood estimation in this Bayesian network.
>
> In the Bayesian network, there will exist a variable of the form
> $R_n^m$ whenever sensor node $n$ "hears" signal $m$. These recorded
> times are stochastically determined by sensor node locations, signal
> emission locations, and emission times, as above. Thus, the
> conditional probability is:
>
> $P(R_n^m | S_n,E_m,T_m) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)}\sigma} \cdot \exp{(
>  \frac{-(T_j + d(S_i,E_j)/c - R_j^i)^2}{2\cdot\sigma^2} )}$
>
> Since there is no global reference frame, we impose the following
> arbitrary conditions to regularize our solution. $S_1$ is the set to
> be $(0,0)$. $S_2$ is set to lie on the positive $x$-axis. $S_3$ is the
> set to lie above the $x$-axis.
>
> Let $L(R | S,E,T)$ be the likelihood of the data given the model in
> the Bayesian network. This likelihood is simply the product of each of
> the conditional probabilities.
>
> Expanding the likelihood, we obtain:
>
> $L(R|S,E,T) = \prod_{m,n} P(R_n^m | S_m,E_n,T_n)$
>
> Since a scalar multiple of the log-likelihood is monotonic in the
> likelihood, we can take the log of Equation (5) and multiply by
> $2\cdot \sigma^2$ to obtain:
>
> $l = \sum_{m,n} -(T_n + \frac{d(S_m,E_n)}{c} - R_n^m)^2$
>
> We use gradient descent with both line search and momentum to maximize
> $l$. Due to the monotonicity of $l$ with the likelihood, this process
> effectively finds the maximum likelihood estimate of the sensor node
> locations given the model parameters.

---

I'm looking to apply this technique, in practice and algorithmically (i.e., in code) to determine the location of *one* signal source, given *four* receivers. Unfortunately, however, I haven't done anything with Bayesian networks for some time (and what I have done is minimal), and I'm not quite following everything here.

I follow up to the line $P(R_n^m | S_n,E_m,T_m)$. I don't quite understand what's going on afterwards? It also isn't entirely clear to me precisely how this would be "generalized" to a 3-dimensional solution.

What's going on here, and how to use it in practice?